# How can i solve Flutter The final variable cant be read error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

In my project i have a auth service but while trying use my service its giving a error like ;

" The final variable "_authService" can't be read coz it is potentially unassigned at this point. Ensure that it is assigned on necessary execution paths.  "

I can show my service like :

```
abstract class IAuthService {
  final String authPath =
      '${IAuthServicePath.BASE_URL.rawValue}${IAuthServicePath.LOGIN}';

  Future<AuthResponseModel?> login(AuthRequstModel model);
}

enum IAuthServicePath { BASE_URL, LOGIN }

extension IAuthServiceExtension on IAuthServicePath {
  String get rawValue {
    switch (this) {
      case IAuthServicePath.LOGIN:
        return '/login';
      case IAuthServicePath.BASE_URL:
        return 'https://reqres.in/api';
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class AuthService extends IAuthService {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();

  @override
  Future<AuthResponseModel?> login(AuthRequstModel model) async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(authPath, data: model);
      print("auth service Response => $response");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // await UserSecureStorage.setField("token", response.data["token"]);
        return AuthResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      }
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

---

My Bloc => :

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(AuthInial()) {
    
    final IAuthService _authService;

    on<LoggedIn>(event, emit) async {
      emit(AuthLoading());
      AuthRequstModel authRequstModel =
          AuthRequstModel(email: event.email, password: event.password);
      final response = await _authService.login(authRequstModel); //Here i can't use it. Coz of error.
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I was forgot to add _authService to constractor.

=>

```
 final IAuthService _authService;
  AuthBloc(this._authService) : super(AuthInial()) {
    on<LoggedIn>(event, emit) async {
      emit(AuthLoading());
      AuthRequstModel authRequstModel =
          AuthRequstModel(email: event.email, password: event.password);
      final response = await _authService.login(authRequstModel);
      print("BLOC RESPONSE=> $response");
      if (response != null) {
        emit(AuthAuthenticated());
      } else {
        emit(AuthUnauthenticated());
      }
    }
  }
}
```